# Show that for every prime $p$ there is a solution to the congruence $x^6-11x^4+36x^2-36 \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Now, plugging and playing, each prime is clearly a solution, but what method would I use to actually prove this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the solutions need to be between $1$ and $p - 1$, or could we just use $x \equiv 0 \equiv p$?

Comment: Does not specify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can factor the left hand of $x^6-11x^4-36x^2-36\equiv 0$ to get
$$(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-6)\equiv 0 \pmod p.$$
So, we can equivalently ask:

> Is it true that at least one of $2$, $3$ and $6$ must be a square mod any prime $p$?

However, this proves fairly easy - the multiplicative group mod $p$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group mod $p-1$ - or equivalently, there is a primitive generator $g$ such that any number coprime to $p$ is congruent to $g^n$ for some $n$. So, for $p>3$, we can let
$$2\equiv g^a\pmod p$$
$$3\equiv g^b \pmod p$$
$$6\equiv g^{a+b}\pmod p.$$
Were $a$ even, then $g^{a/2}$ would be a square root of $2$, for instance. As one of $a$, $b$ or $a+b$ must be even, one of $2$, $3$, or $6$ must have a square root. (This fact is equally well expressed in the fact that the [Legendre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) is multiplicative in its numerator)

Comment: Great answer @Meelo !

Comment: If u and v are not quadratic residues, then uv is a quadratic residue since (-1)(-1) = 1.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ f (x) = (x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-6)\ $ Show that either $2,3$ or $6$ must be a square mod $p$ using standard theory about quadratic residues.